# How to set the property value for model object in action class using ModelDriven in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, model-driven

Using this code:

**StudentAction.java:**

```
public class StudentAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven {

    private List studentList;
    Student student;
    StudentDAO sdo = new StudentDAO();
   
    public String delete() {
        System.out.println("delete action");
        System.out.println(student.getId()); //not setting value of id
        
        sdo.delete(student.getId());

        return SUCCESS;
    }

  @Override
  public Object getModel() {
    return student;
 }
 //getter and setter
}
```

**Student.java:**

```
public class Student  implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    //getter and setter
}
```

**In JSP:**

```
<s:iterator value="studentList" var="ss">
    <s:property value="id"/>
    <s:property value="name"/>
    <s:property value="address"/>
    <a href="delete?id= <s:property value="id"/>">delete</a><br>
</s:iterator><br>
```

When I pass the value of `id` from JSP to `delete` action I want to initialize `Student`'s `id` property.

How to do this?

Comment: What @RomanC is asking is that where is your Model ? How are you implementing the `ModelDriven` functionality in your action

Comment: @SaifAsif Actually, I needed to know how it's implemented, because the code won't compile without it.

Comment: Thats another thing. I was assuming that its implemented properly by OP

Comment: @SaifAsif No, it is necessary part of the code and your assumptions are indefinite.

Comment: true for the "necessary part of the code"

Comment: @SaifAsif My model is Student

Answer (score 1):

Use the action field to set the parameter `id`:

```
public class StudentAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List studentList;
    Student student;
    StudentDAO sdo = new StudentDAO();
     private Long id;
    //getter and setter


    public String delete() {
        System.out.println("delete action");
        System.out.println(getId()); 

        sdo.delete(getId());

        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

One more thing if you want to implement `ModelDriven` you should add the code for your model

```
private Student model = new Student();

public Object getModel() {
  return model;
}
```

The code is like in the documentation [example](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/model-driven.html#example).

Comment: Insted of using seperate Id i want to initialize `Student` pojo's id

Comment: Inste of `sdo.delete(getId());` i want to use `sdo.delete(student.getId());`

Comment: That way you should instantiate a `Student` object before the parameters are set.

Comment: but this is inside the iterate but this is not initializing i tried

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer to show you where the model is initialized.